# How to always have a positive output in java or how to use |-3| = 3

Tags: java

So I have many inputs and I always want to have the postive difference between the number which operator should I use

lets say

```
T1     T2       Output

3       5          2
7       6          1
5       9          4
```

Comment: No idea, how you process your input, but have a look at Math.abs(int).

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) for `Math.abs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Math.abs()` method.
Returns the absolute value of an int/double/float/long value (depending on the type of incoming parameter).

For example:

```
int output = Math.abs(T1 - T2);
System.out.println(output);
```

//or

```
System.out.println(Math.abs(T1 - T2));
```

Comment: @NOOBDEV glad to help you) click a "best answer V" button, please.